# Can i wrap the OAuth 2.0 results in custom objects?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I see samples where OAuth is returned as json as such:

```
        {
          "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZSHB-aaa",
          "token_type" : "Bearer",
          "expires_in" : 3600,
          "refresh_token" : "1/LkGHrqtU"
          "scope" : "ALL"
        }
```

My question is, is there any harm in wrapping up this in a custom object?

ie:the diff is the strong object name/wrapper being included in the return json.  I just want to know if this would still be considered as a 'standard' OAuth provider.

```
{"OAuthResult":{"access_token":"abc","refresh_token":"123","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3900"}}
```

I have read the spec and see that you MUST include a GET for obtaining the token, but i don't recall the return object being specifically spec'd?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the current (v2-31) OAuth2 draft, section 5.1:

> The parameters are included in the entity body of the HTTP response
>   using the "application/json" media type as defined by [RFC4627]. **The 
>   parameters are serialized into a JSON structure by adding each parameter
>   at the highest structure level**. Parameter names and string values are
>   included as JSON strings.  Numerical values are included
>   as JSON numbers.  The order of parameters does not matter and can vary.

So you will NOT be 'standard' with such a response.